# how to select specific drop down list Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

`ddlCountry` is already bind

```
ddlCountry.DataValueField= "CountryId"
ddlCountry.DataTextFiled= "CountryName";
ddlCountry.DataSource= objCountry.Select();
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

using above technique.

Now on gridview selectedIndex changed event i want to set the Value of dropdown. how can i do this??
 behind gridview selected index change i am doing this code

```
ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = gvCountry.SelectRow.Cells[1].text;
```

**but this is making duplicate of the item**
 so what i need to do which ddl property will select my desired text ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work

```
ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(gvCountry.SelectRow.Cells[1].text).selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows

```
string gridText = gvCountry.SelectRow.Cells[1].text;

if (ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(gridText) != null)
{
    ddlCountry.ClearSelection();
    ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(gridText).Selected = true;
}
```